# JavaFX: Listen to Scene changes

Tags: java, javafx

How can I make a custom Event that triggers on `Stage.setScene()`?
In my code, the button switches the Scenes and that works fine. However, I would like to extend the Stage to have an additional Event that is triggered when a button or possibly any other Element triggers a setScene.

Example:

```java
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Group g1 = new Group();
        Button b1 = new Button("2");
        g1.getChildren().setAll(b1);
        Scene scene1 = new Scene(g1, 50, 50);

        Group g2 = new Group();
        Button b2 = new Button("1");
        g2.getChildren().setAll(b2);
        Scene scene2 = new Scene(g2, 50, 50);

        stage.setScene(scene1);
        stage.setTitle("JavaFX Application Life Cycle");

        b1.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            System.out.println("1");
            stage.setScene(scene2);
        });
        b2.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            System.out.println("2");
            stage.setScene(scene1);
        });
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a `ChangeListener<Scene>` to your `Stage` like this:

```java
stage.sceneProperty().addListener((observable, oldScene, newScene) -> {
    System.out.println("New scene: " + newScene);
    System.out.println("Old scene: " + oldScene);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe using a listener, as shown in [the answer by @M.S.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59687151/6395627), is probably the best and simplest way to react to scene changes. However, you ask about how to make a "custom event" that you can fire when the scene changes; by "event" I assume you mean a subclass of `javafx.event.Event`. So while I recommend sticking with a simple listener, here's an example of a custom event.

First, you need a custom event class:

```java
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Window;

public class SceneChangedEvent extends Event {

  public static final EventType<SceneChangedEvent> SCENE_CHANGED =
      new EventType<>(Event.ANY, "SCENE_CHANGED");
  public static final EventType<SceneChangedEvent> ANY = SCENE_CHANGED;

  private transient Window window;
  private transient Scene oldScene;
  private transient Scene newScene;

  public SceneChangedEvent(Window window, Scene oldScene, Scene newScene) {
    super(window, window, SCENE_CHANGED);
    this.window = window;
    this.oldScene = oldScene;
    this.newScene = newScene;
  }

  public Window getWindow() {
    return window;
  }

  public Scene getOldScene() {
    return oldScene;
  }

  public Scene getNewScene() {
    return newScene;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what information you want to carry with the event so I just added the source `Window` as well as the old and new `Scene`s. If you're wondering about the `ANY = SCENE_CHANGED`, I'm just following the pattern used by `javafx.event.ActionEvent` (which also only has a single event-type).

Then you simply need to fire the event when the scene changes. To implement this you're still going to need a change listener. As you mention wanting to extend `Stage` here's an example of that:

```java
import javafx.beans.NamedArg;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class CustomStage extends Stage {

  private final ObjectProperty<EventHandler<? super SceneChangedEvent>> onSceneChanged =
      new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "onSceneChanged") {
        @Override
        protected void invalidated() {
          setEventHandler(SceneChangedEvent.SCENE_CHANGED, get());
        }
      };

  public final void setOnSceneChanged(EventHandler<? super SceneChangedEvent> handler) {
    onSceneChanged.set(handler);
  }

  public final EventHandler<? super SceneChangedEvent> getOnSceneChanged() {
    return onSceneChanged.get();
  }

  public final ObjectProperty<EventHandler<? super SceneChangedEvent>> onSceneChangedProperty() {
    return onSceneChanged;
  }

  public CustomStage() {
    this(StageStyle.DECORATED);
  }

  public CustomStage(@NamedArg(value = "style", defaultValue = "DECORATED") StageStyle style) {
    super(style);
    sceneProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> fireEvent(new SceneChangedEvent(this, ov, nv)));
  }
}
```

This would let you react to the scene changing using any of the following:

```java
CustomStage stage = new CustomStage();

// addEventFilter/addEventHandler
stage.addEventFilter(SceneChangedEvent.SCENE_CHANGED, e -> { ... });
stage.addEventHandler(SceneChangedEvent.SCENE_CHANGED, e -> { ... });

// setOnSceneChanged
stage.setOnSceneChanged(e -> { ... });
```

Keep in mind that the event will only target the `CustomStage` instance. In other words, only event handlers added to the `CustomStage` instance will be notified of the event. And as you can see, this is much more complicated than simply adding a change listener to the `scene` property of the `Stage`.

Comment: Wow that is a very detailed answer, greatly appreciate it. I'll need some time to fully read and understand it. I'll get to it as soon as I can (which will be sunday unfortunately). Additional Info: I have a Scene that changes something in an ObservableList that is used in other Scene and even thou I've bound Scenes to that ObservableList, only the currently displayed one displays the changes. So when I switch to that other Scene, I would like to force the TableView.refresh(). I've tried the refresh with a button and that works great. Now I would like to automate it :)

Comment: using listeners to the stage's scene property is _the_ solution, whatever the problem. Going custom event is adding unneeded complexity to a setup that sounds  weird .. also note the calling tableView.refresh is _always_ wrong (to at least 4th approximation)